# inject EJB bean in Servlet BOTTLENECK

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, servlet-3.0

As I know EJB container has session beans's pool. i.e. when client look ups bean from JNDI, ejb container creates new instance or returns it from pool. 
Stateless Session bean's one instance is doing one request at time, when other request come to this bean, ejb container creates new one or returns in from pool.

everything is ok, but suppose we `Inject` bean into `Servlet`

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean {}

@WebSerlvet
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    StatelessBean bean;

    public void doPost() {
         bean.handle();
    }
```

Servlets instance is always one. when multiple clients request this servlet, is run in different Thread only. So Injected `Stateless Bean` is shared by those threads. So when multiple thread call `bean.handle()` method,

- is this bottleneck?
- does Ejb container creates new one (I think this is impossible)?,
- when ejb container multiplies bean, when client looks up from JNDI, or when client calls method on bean's instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject EJB using `@EJB` actually you've got a proxy to this EJB, not particular bean instance. By using this proxy container selects a bean instance from the beans pool. Using your example - this way two separate clients requests to servlet can be served by two separate EJB bean instances, so definitely this is no bottleneck. 
Container can create new instance of bean when there is no available free instance to select from the pool (provided the number of current active bean instances doesn't exceed maximum bean pool size). This is done when a client (e.g. servlet) sends a request (invokes a method) to EJB bean to perform an operation.

I can suggest you that if you want to observe when EJB bean instance is created you could read about `@PostConstruct` annotated method.